# insert into column family with case sensitive column name

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am using the following Cassandra/CQL versions:

[cqlsh 4.0.1 | Cassandra 2.0.1 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.37.0]

I am trying to insert data into a pre-existing CF with case sensitive column names. I hit "unknown identifier" errors when trying to insert data.

Following is how the column family is described:

```
CREATE TABLE "Sample_List_CS" (
  key text,
  column1 text,
  "fName" text,
  "ipSubnet" text,
  "ipSubnetMask" text,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, column1)
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=0 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  replicate_on_write='false' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='NONE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

CREATE INDEX ipSubnet ON "Sample_List_CS" ("ipSubnet");
```

The insert statements result in errors:

```
cqlsh:Sample_KS> INSERT INTO "Sample_List_CS" (key,column1,"fName") VALUES    ('123','1','myValue');
Bad Request: Unknown identifier fName

cqlsh:Sample_KS> INSERT INTO "Sample_List_CS" (key,column1,"ipSubnet") VALUES    ('123','1','255');
Bad Request: Unknown identifier ipSubnet
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've run these commands with `[cqlsh 4.1.0 | Cassandra 2.0.2 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.38.0]` and they work for me. (without the `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` on `CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: thanks for validating, I tried the same without compact storage and it worked too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it when using `WITH COMPACT STORAGE` a table may only have one column other than the primary key.

As quoted in [the manual](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/webhelp/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html):

> Using the compact storage directive prevents you from adding more than
>   one column that is not part of the PRIMARY KEY.

For you that means you can only have one of these 4 columns in your table:

- "fName"
- "ipSubnet"
- "ipSubnetMask"
- value

(Alternatively, you could add 3 of them to the primary key definition.)

Thus it makes sense that the other three columns lead to an `Unknown identifier` error.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. It turns out that the pre-existing column family was created using hector api and is configured for 'compact storage' by default. Your reasoning looks to be correct, I created a new CF without compact storage and things work fine.