# ParseException: no viable alternative at input

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I was trying to run the below query in Azure data bricks.

```py
query=s"""WITH pre_file_user AS(
            SELECT id,
            typeid,
          CASE when dttm is null or dttm='' then cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' as timestamp)
          else cast(dttm as timestamp)
          end as dttm
          from dde_pre_file_user_supp
)"""

spark.sql(query)
```

then I was getting the following error

> ParseException:no viable alternative at input 'with pre_file_users AS
> (\n select id, \n typid, in case\n when dttm is null or dttm = '' then
> cast('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 as timestamp)\n end as dttm\n from
> dde_pre_file_user_supp\n  )'

Can I use WITH clause in data bricks or is there any alternative?

Comment: You're just declaring the CTE but not using it. Try adding `select * from pre_file_user` after the cte

Answer (score 6):

I have mentioned reasons that may cause *‘no viable alternative at input’*  error:

1. The *‘no viable alternative at input’* error message happens when we type a character that doesn’t fit in the context of that line.
2. Also check if data type for some field may mismatch.

The *‘no viable alternative at input‘* error doesn’t mention which incorrect character we used.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32117302) answer by [piotrwest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690347/piotrwest)

Also refer this [article](https://kodify.net/tradingview/errors/no-viable-alternative/#fixing-tradingviews-no-viable-alternative-at-character-error)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you're mapping the select into a POJO constructor and miss the ending parenthesis, you'll also get this issue.

e.g.

```
SELECT new ${Foo.class.name} (f.id, f.active
FROM FooDomain f
```

Answer (score 0):

Also there might be cases where you might have missed out adding `native query = true`

Please don't forget to check that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).